# how to make template append to a specefic view from controller

Tags: grails

My question is, I have a page say `view.gsp` and containing a form that calls an action `save` in my controller say `MyController.groovy` on submission. Now what I want to do is, when the details have been successfully saved in the database, I want to go back to that page(`view.gsp`) or rather stay there, using remote call or submit.

How do I do that?

Also, mainly, I want to append a text saying, 'your details have been saved successfully' or 'please enter details again' on failure. Can I do this creating a template and then rendering it from the `MyController`? How?

Comment: I doubt you'll get any more help until you accept some of the help you've already been given.

Comment: damn, I'm sorry, I'm new to this site, don't really know how things are done..

Comment: Don't worry, it's an easy fix ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are going to both create(save) and edit(update) using the same form and action?

Your `save` action at some point will either `redirect` or `render` a particular view, based on whether the save was successful.  Since you always want to render the same view regardless of whether it saves or not I would do this:

```
def save = {
    def propertyInstance 
    //you need to do this since you are both saving and updating in the same action
    if(params.id) {
        propertyInstance = Property.get(params.id)
        propertyInstance.properties = params
    } else {
        propertyInstance = new Property(params)
    }

    if (propertyInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message="Property ${propertyInstance?.id} : ${propertyInstance?.address} has been added successfully"
    }
    else {
        flash.message = "Please enter details again"
    }
    render(view: "view", model: [propertyInstance: propertyInstance])
}
```

And then in your `view.gsp` you can show what you set in the `flash.message` like this:

```
 <g:if test="${flash.message}">
     <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
 </g:if>
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted to use a template (called `_addressMessage.gsp` for example) to show a message with some formatting (like the parts if of the address on separate lines) you could do something like this in your `view.gsp` wherever you wanted the message to show up:

```
<g:if test="${propertyInstance.address}">
    <g:render template="addressMessage" model="[propertyInstance: propertyInstance]" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
    Please enter details again.
</g:else>
```

I included the `<g:if...` in there since I think you don't want to show this if there is no address.

Comment: Actually the reason i asked if i could use template was because its not just a plain text message. the message needs to be something like this- "property (id of property here) : (address of property here) has been added. this is why i created a template and i was wondering if i can render this template from my controller in my view.gsp- my template looks something like this- Property ${propertyInstance?.id} : ${propertyInstance?.address} has been added successfully

Comment: Well I guess you could create a small template and pass it the propertyInstance.  In that case you could embed the template in the view.gsp, and pass it the propertyInstance model. I'll add a small update to the answer.  But that seems overly complicated - what you are showing the user is still just a plain text message.  Unless there is something else that you haven't stated yet I would still do it as above - just make you flash.message="Property ${propertyInstance?.id} : ${propertyInstance?.address} has been added successfully"

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll explain why I'm choosing to go for the template instead of the flash message. It's because I want the message to be appended/displayed in the view every time the user enters new details, right below the old message. So if he has entered details 5 times, there should be 5 messages on the view page showing details of is properties. And the (street) has to be a link to take him to the list action(). I understand this is complicated. :(